# Why does this split a number when adding it to a list

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def average_growth(stock,time):
    a=0
    b=time-1
    average_time=[]
    while b<13:
        x=int(((stock[b]-stock[a])/time))
        average_time+=str(x)
        a+=1
        b+=1
    print(x)

average_growth({0: 317.68, 1: 396.05, 2: 451.48, 3: 428.03, 4: 516.26, 5: 604.83},2)
```

I am trying to average stock data for specific intervals of time and add the averages into a list entitled "average time". When str(x) is added to the list average time however, it splits the number into two seperate entries. For example, 65 goes to a list with ["6","5"]. Negative numbers add a "-" to the list. Is there a way to stop this from happening and preserve the number?

Comment: You should put str(x) in its own list. That is, try [str(x)].  You could also store numbers in average_time instead of strings.  I.e. average_time+=[x].  Then you can convert the elements of the list to strings with map(str,x).

Comment: Pleaseputmorespacesinyourcode

Answer (score 4):

`+=` is used to concatenate a list, not append an element. Either use:

```
average_time += [str(x)]
```

or

```
average_time.append(str(x))
```